# File permissions on Docker, Windows 10 Wsl2 Ubuntu, Yii2

Tags: docker, yii2, windows-10, file-permissions, wsl-2

I used to connect to DigitalOcean droplet for yii2 development. Now, I want to setup yii2 with docker environment. While the docker-compose is setup and running, I got several issues with file permission.

In Yii, I usually  run migrations scripts or gii to generate models and CRUD page. My setup:

- folders that will be written by yii to have `775` and ownership of `myusername.www-data`
- I put the `myusername` user to be in group `www-data`
- I prefer not to use 777 to avoid forgetting them to be properly setup when running live

I understand that this is only dev environment when we can use 777 safely.

I was wondering what would be the best practice to setup the yii2 dev environment in windows 10 wsl2 ubuntu and docker.

Thank you,

Daniel